# Meteor error, Handsontable not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, handsontable

I've installed the Handsontable package from atmosphere, and defining tables works fine in my app except for when I try to create a custom cell renderer.

The offending code in defining the table is this column definition:

```
{
  type: { 
    renderer: function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
      Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
      $(td).css({
        background: 'yellow'
      });
    }},
    //format: '0, 0.00 $',
    readOnly: true
  }
```

Anytime I try to make a Hansontable call like the *Handsontable.Textcell.renderer.apply* above, Meteor throws this error:

> *Exception from Deps afterFlush function: ReferenceError: Handsontable is not defined*

I did read that Handsontable uses Jquery 1.9, but Meteor is bundled with 1.8. Could this be an issue?

Every example I see of custom cell renderers in Handsontable is similar to what I have so I'm a pretty lost on what the problem is. I also created a custom package of Handsontable with the latest version and that didn't help either.

Would love any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a bug in the Handsontable package.

This line: https://github.com/olragon/meteor-handsontable/blob/master/lib/jquery.handsontable.full.js#L13

```
var Handsontable = {
```

should be

```
Handsontable = {
```

In meteor files are variable scoped. If you use the `var` keyword then other files can't access it. This is part of the reason you get the `Handsontable is not defined` error

You also have to export it by adding the line below after https://github.com/olragon/meteor-handsontable/blob/master/package.js#L6

```
api.export("Handsontable");
```

So that the api is exposed out of the package.

I have made a pull request so the package maintainer needs to accept it and update the package on atmosphere then you can run `mrt update` and use your code as you are using now.

If you are in a rush you could fork the package with the updates and use that as your `Handsontable` package

https://github.com/olragon/meteor-handsontable/pull/1